# In deleted comments, the moderator's name appears with the same background used for the user who asked the question

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-comments

On this answer, I deleted some comments, and I have noticed that, in the deleted comments, my name appears with the same background used for the user who asked the question.

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't happens for other users.

[image: screenshot]

The problem is the CSS class associated with the `<a>` markup, since that is `<a href="/users/199/kiamlaluno" class="comment-user owner">kiamlaluno<span class="mod-flair" title="moderator">♦</span></a>`.

It doesn't happen for the question itself, though.

[image: screenshot]